# I don’t understand the use of the particle に in the following sentence

Tags: particle-に

私にまかせてください。I only know に as a destination particle.

Comment: Please look up に in a dictionary or grammar book.  There are many definitions for it.

Comment: Is に indicating the indirect object of the action allow here?

Comment: 私に（それを）まかせてください。 <- Maybe that helps you have an Idea, japanese language usually omits things that can be understood by context.

Answer (score 3):

> 私にまかせてください。

is translated to 'Please leave it *to* me.'

The *to* in the sentence there is the destination particle.

It would be the same in

私にください (Please give it *to* me)

or

私に話してください (Please talk *to* me)。

に can be used as a destination particle OR a indirect object reference.

I hope this helps.

Comment: is it really the destinantion particle or the indirect object one?

Comment: I think it is both, depending on how it is used. Thank you, I will add that.